# Find $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ such that $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ and $\sum a_kb_k\sin(xb_k)$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I was doing an exercise concerning uniform convergence of series of functions and I got stuck trying to finish the following:

Give an example of sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ such that

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely.
- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k '$ does not converge pointwise.

Where $f_k(x):=a_k\cos(xb_k)$

I started by setting $a_n=-1/n^2$, but I cannot find $(b_n)$ such that the series of the derivatives $f_k'(x)=\frac{1}{k^2} b_k\sin(xb_k)$ diverges.
My problem is that I cannot bound the $\sin$ function from below and I do not know the behavior of $\sin(xb_k)$ as $k$ changes. Indeed, fixing any $x$, its sign changes as a "messy" function of $k$.

Is my plan correct? 
Should I try with a different $(a_n)$?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with $b_k=k^3$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I tried, but I have problems figuring out how to deal with $\sin(k^3x)$ for fixed $x$, since its sign changes as $k$ does. Intuitively, it seems to me that half of the time the $\sin$ is positive and it is negative for the rest of time, which makes divergence difficult to prove (if the sum actually diverges)

Comment: Try $b_k=k^3$ and $x=\pi/2$...

Comment: @sranthrop Thank you very much, I think I solved it. Again I had to deal with $\sin(k^3\pi/2)$ changing sign, but at least the pattern is very simple in this case.

Comment: You're very welcome :)